# Drools date comparision when part of the rule

Tags: java, drools-guvnor

I need to write following condition in when part of rule.

start_date<=end_date+3 months
where start_date and end_date are fields of type Date.

Would anyone please tell me how can I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do date calculation in drools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40781259/how-to-do-date-calculation-in-drools)

Comment: I have already gone through that. I need to add 3 months in LHS part, while in the question you mentioned, it's done in RHS part.

Comment: Nope. In the mentioned question it is done in the LHS. The LHS is the evaluation part between `when` and `then`, the RHS is the consequence part between `then` and `end`. But, I'll answer your question if that is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it feels like a very weird rule. WHEN the `start_date` is later then or exactly three month after the `end_date` THEN execute a consequence.

I'm assuming `start_date` and `end_date` are fields of a class `Foo`, the rule will be as follows:

```
rule "I am checking if the start_date of Foo is more than or exactly three month after the end_date of Foo"
when
    Foo($start: start_date, $end: end_date, 
        $end_plus_3_month: DateUtils.addMonths($end, 3), 
        $start.compareTo($end_plus_3_month) <= 0)
then
    System.out.printf("The start_date %tD is more that or exactly 3 month after %tD.%n", $start, $end);
end
```